hyperref with line-breaking stop working when uploading to physical review journal
I am trying to properly break links in the reference section of my article when submitting to physical review journals. I searched a lot but could not fix this problem. I am using the recommended revtex4-2 format with the \usepackage{hyperref} option. This creates links that are sometimes too long to be inside the page. I tried using the option \hypersetup{breaklinks=true} and this does break the link into two lines but then the link is no longer clickable and doesn't work. I am checking things with the "preview PDF" option in the manuscripts submission process in physical review. I tried many different combination and things people suggested but the problem persists. Either the link is too long to appear on the page or you can't click it anymore.
I created a minimal example that recreates the problem:
\documentclass[
 reprint,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true, colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\preprint{APS/123-QED}
\title{This is my example}

\author{auther authrrr}
\email{jgfhgjhg}
\affiliation{universe}

%\pacs{PACS}

\begin{abstract}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccccccccc dddddddddddddddddd
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The transport of molecules, colloids and particulate matter in diso\cite{scher1975anomalous}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}%
\makeatletter
\providecommand \@ifxundefined [1]{%
 \@ifx{#1\undefined}
}%
\providecommand \@ifnum [1]{%
 \ifnum #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \@ifx [1]{%
 \ifx #1\expandafter \@firstoftwo
 \else \expandafter \@secondoftwo
 \fi
}%
\providecommand \natexlab [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \enquote  [1]{``#1''}%
\providecommand \bibnamefont  [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \bibfnamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \citenamefont [1]{#1}%
\providecommand \href@noop [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \href [0]{\begingroup \@sanitize@url \@href}%
\providecommand \@href[1]{\@@startlink{#1}\@@href}%
\providecommand \@@href[1]{\endgroup#1\@@endlink}%
\providecommand \@sanitize@url [0]{\catcode `\\12\catcode `\$12\catcode `\&12\catcode `\#12\catcode `\^12\catcode `\_12\catcode `\%12\relax}%
\providecommand \@@startlink[1]{}%
\providecommand \@@endlink[0]{}%
\providecommand \url  [0]{\begingroup\@sanitize@url \@url }%
\providecommand \@url [1]{\endgroup\@href {#1}{\urlprefix }}%
\providecommand \urlprefix  [0]{URL }%
\providecommand \Eprint [0]{\href }%
\providecommand \doibase [0]{https://doi.org/}%
\providecommand \selectlanguage [0]{\@gobble}%
\providecommand \bibinfo  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \bibfield  [0]{\@secondoftwo}%
\providecommand \translation [1]{[#1]}%
\providecommand \BibitemOpen [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemStop [0]{}%
\providecommand \bibitemNoStop [0]{.\EOS\space}%
\providecommand \EOS [0]{\spacefactor3000\relax}%
\providecommand \BibitemShut  [1]{\csname bibitem#1\endcsname}%
\let\auto@bib@innerbib\@empty
%</preamble>
\bibitem [{\citenamefont {Scher}\ and\ \citenamefont {Montroll}(1975)}]{scher1975anomalous}%
  \BibitemOpen
  \bibfield  {author} {\bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {H.}~\bibnamefont {Scher}}\ and\ \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {E.~W.}\ \bibnamefont {Montroll}},\ }\bibfield  {title} {\bibinfo {title} {Anomalous transit-time dispersion in amorphous solids},\ }\href {https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.12.2455} {\bibfield  {journal} {\bibinfo  {journal} {Physical Review B xxxxx vvvvvvvvvvv aaaaaaaaaaaa}\ }\textbf {\bibinfo {volume} {12}},\ \bibinfo {pages} {2455} (\bibinfo {year} {1975})}\BibitemShut {NoStop}%
\end{thebibliography}%

\end{document}


This does break the link into two lines and it appears in blue color but you can't click on it anymore.
Here is the output, the blue part is not clickable


the journal seems to compile with latex+dvips. Try \usepackage{hypdvips} after hyperref.

This doesn't fix the problem unfortunately.

sorry but at best ask the journal how this should be handled. They should know if links are meant to work.
